# How to set RAM in installation of HAXM

Tags: android, haxm

I am trying to re-install HAXM  to reconfigure RAM it occupies but when I run the installer it shows three options 
1) Repair 
2) Change 
3) Remove

but first two are disabled so I removed HAXM and then tried to install it again, then  it did not ask me for RAM which is why installed.
my question is how to set RAM in installation of HAXM

Answer (score 0):

As shown on [Intel's HAXM Installation Instructions](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows), the RAM setting is no longer available as of HAXM 6.2.0. I suspect you're trying to install a version that no longer has the option.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts